# Logical AND in shell script while loop

Tags: shell

I am trying to compare dates in the `while` loop of a shell script. The shell script will be controlled by 2 conditions, like the following:

```
while [ $currentDate -le $currentDateMonthEnd -a $currentDate -le $toDate ]; do
...
done
```

The above is my current code, which complains of `"integer expression expected"`. I have also tried using `&&` and `AND`, which also do not work and complains of mismatching braces.

Could someone please provide the syntax to make the above comparison?

Comment: One of the variables is not set, or is not a number. You should test the code using something like `set -x`

Comment: If you are trying to compare full dates as it is, this will not work - as @Petesh notes, a date is not a number. You have to subtract your dates and check the delta/compare the individual days/months/years.

Comment: You might want to consider replacing shell scripting, in this application, with a real programming language that has date math functions; you'll probably find that it makes your life much easier to do so.

Comment: If you make your date format look like 20130610 for 2013-06-10 (10th June 2013), then you can compare numerically into date order.  Pretty much any other date format is not as conventient.

Comment: @Pretesh, you were right. If you could put that as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1):

```
dc ()
{
  [ $(date +%s -d "$1") $2 $(date +%s -d "$3") ]
}

while dc "$currentDate" -le "$currentDateMonthEnd" && dc "$currentDate" -le "$toDate"
do
  # ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

following code works for me,

```
#! /bin/bash

toDate=`echo 2014/03/30 | tr -d "/"`
currentDate=`date +"%Y/%m/%d" | tr -d "/"`
currentDateMonthEnd=`date +%Y/%m/%d -d "-$(date +%d) days +1 month" | tr -d "/"` 

while [[ $currentDate -le $currentDateMonthEnd ]] && [[ $currentDate -le $toDate ]]   
do   
...  
done


#! /bin/sh 

while [ $currentDate -le $currentDateMonthEnd ] && [ $currentDate -le $toDate ] 
do   
...  
done
```